# -bash: sudo: command not found Mac OS X (EC2 CLI prob?)

Tags: macos, bash, sudo

Getting the error:
`-bash: sudo: command not found` 
`echo $PATH` outputs `PATH:EC2_HOME/bin`

I'm running Mac OSX 10.8.3

That seems wrong even for a n00b like me.
How do I fix my $PATH and return my computer to it's former self?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As stated in the comments the right files to set up your `$PATH` variable are: `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/opt/x11/bin:$PATH
```

In this way when you re-enter in the console your `PATH` will work fine.
You can add other directories to your `$PATH` as you like.

If you just copy and past that line in an active console you just set the `PATH` variable temporary, when you logout and login again you will loose your path, so add it in your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: The trailing slashes are unnecessary. Note that this will lengthen your `$PATH` for each new shell, which is mostly harmless but annoying.

Comment: Removed the unnecessary trailing slashes

Comment: The .bashrc is notionally the wrong place to do this, ideally you should use ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login (depending on however you're set up) so that potentially expensive environment setup only has to be run once, then *inherited* by all the subshells running ~/.bashrc.  And the login shell doesn't run .bashrc anyway unless ~/.bash_login or ~/.bash_profile is set up to do it.

Comment: Thanks @KeithThompson and @Alex North-Keys, I've edited my answer, I've switched to `zsh` from to much time :-)

Comment: where can open    ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile without terminal?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you've managed to get into that state, though [this article](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2621/os_x_change_path_environment_variable/) explains how you can set your path.

If it helps, the output from my echo $PATH is: -

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Comment: I *hope* the first element is `/usr/bin`, not `usr/bin`.

Comment: @KeithThompson, you're absolutely right and thanks for spotting the error of my copy and paste. I've corrected the answer ;O)

Answer (score 1):

1. go to shell
2. choose new command
3. put this : `sudo vim .bash_profile`
4. then put : `export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/opt/x11/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`echo $PATH`

Followed by:

`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"`